# How to see keyboard modifiers when program launched from windows?

Tags: c++, qt

I have a Qt application and would like to determine if Shift (or Ctrl) key was held down when the application was launched.  My goal is to implement a "safe mode" for the application.

I have tried using `QApplication::keyboardModifiers()` but that function always returns 0 (no modifiers) no matter what keys I have held down when start the app, either by double-clicking it or starting from the command line.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    QString homeDocs = QStandardPaths::writableLocation(QStandardPaths::DocumentsLocation)+"/";
    QCoreApplication::setApplicationName(getAppName());
    QCoreApplication::setOrganizationName(getDeveloperName());
    QCoreApplication::setOrganizationDomain(getDeveloperDomain());

    QSettings settings;

    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QStringList args = a.arguments();

    Qt::KeyboardModifiers test = QApplication::keyboardModifiers();
```

Receiving a code of 0 but was expecting bit flags indicating which keys were held down.

Comment: @eyllanesc: Event handling is only one way of processing keyboard state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `QApplication::queryKeyboardModifiers()` instead of `QApplication::keyboardModifiers()`.

See the [docs](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qapplication.html#queryKeyboardModifiers) for more details.

Example:

```cpp
Qt::KeyboardModifiers key = QApplication::queryKeyboardModifiers();

if(key == Qt::ShiftModifier){
    qDebug() << "Shift key is pressed";
}

if(key == Qt::ControlModifier){
    qDebug() << "Ctrl key is pressed";
}
```

Comment: This did exactly what I needed.  Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

I think you tend to implemente a function that will be run when Ctrl was pressed enough time.
 You can override mousePressEvent to confirm Ctrl is pressed and start a timer, then you should alse override mouseReleaseEvent to confirm how long time ctrl pressed by the timer.